# chronoforms v5 static attachment

Tags: chronoforms

I've a problem sending an email with chronoforms V5 with a static attachment using some variables for the path:

THIS WORKS 
(no variables)

```
<?php
 $path = JPATH_SITE.'/avvisi/B/';
$form->files['avvisobonario']['path'] = $path.'attachment1.rar';
?>
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK (with variables)

```
<?php
$path = JPATH_SITE.'/avvisi/{avviso_cartella}/';
$form->files['avvisobonario']['path'] = $path.'{avviso_mavpdf}';
?>
```

Please note that I assured that the content of the variables is right
in other words: {avviso_cartella}  is B  and {avviso_mavpdf} is attachment1.rar

Could anyone help me please? I think that it is a very very simple problem but I don't know what to do

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you can’t use the {} short codes in php, use $form->data[‘name’] instead